# Stop running extern Alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

How can I stop a running alarm with the android API (version 2.2 or 4.4) from another App? The "stopping-app" is started for instance with a Bluetooth signal.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I looked for AlarmManager and AlarmClock but both don't provide a way to stop an alarm. 
I just wonder if I have to write an alarm app on my own(which is not what I would prefer) to be possible to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Watching the logcat while stopping the alarm manually gives the following:

```
07-02 02:15:12.363: V/AlarmClock(30848): AlarmStateManager received intent Intent { act=change_state cat=[DISMISS_TAG] dat=content://com.android.deskclock/instances/1  flg=0x10000010 cmp=com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.alarms.AlarmStateManager bnds=[637,346][1080,490] (has extras) }
07-02 02:15:12.363: V/AlarmClock(30848): Setting dismissed state to instance 1
07-02 02:15:12.363: V/AlarmClock(30848): Clearing notifications for alarm instance: 1
07-02 02:15:12.373: V/AlarmClock(30848): Canceling instance 1 timers
07-02 02:15:12.383: I/AlarmClock(30848): Disabling parent alarm: 2
07-02 02:15:12.393: V/AlarmClock(30848): AlarmService.onStartCommand() with intent: Intent { act=STOP_ALARM dat=content://com.android.deskclock/instances/1 cmp=com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.alarms.AlarmService }
```

especially the last line seems interesting. maybe it's possible to create that intent on your own to stop the alarm..